# Push a UIViewController within a UITabBarController's UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController with 4 tabs. Each tab is a UINavigationController with UIViewController loaded as its RootViewController.
Ex:

```
Tab1ViewController* viewC = [[Tab1ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController* navCDisc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: viewC];
```

On tap of a button in my Tab1ViewController, I now have to push a new UIViewController on top of the existing one. How can i achieve this?

In Tab1ViewController.m file , i tried:

```
UIViewController *newVC = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newVC];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newVC animated:YES];
```

This behaves strangely and automatically switches tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIViewController *newVC = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newVC animated:YES];
```

Just this, don't create another UINavigationController. If it doesn't work, make sure the code is executed and self.navigationController is not nil (put a breakpoint); if it is, it will work